# Similar to Tinder Instagram Connect

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I noticed that apps like Tinder can show Instagram connect of lets say, User A on everyone else's phones even without requiring other users to actually sign into instagram.

For example: User-A connects instagram and gets access token. Users-B, C, D... can see A's public & private pictures without even logging into instagram.

Is there a way to view another user's instagram without requiring access token - even private pictures by just using CLIENT_ID?

Comment: does any of answers put the light on what you was asking? I also have a suggestion to update the subject of the question, as it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Farside Your answer is very bad. Please read the question again - "is there a way to view another user's instagram without access token - even private pictures by just using CLIENT_ID?"

Comment: but I mentioned this. If in short - no, there's no way to see another user's instagram without access token. Access_token still *requires granting of access*, and *Authentication*. If it would be possible - it would be serious security vulnerability in accessing private data.

Comment: Legolas, I explicitly extended my answer, so now you see the explicit answer on your question, with explanation why not. If it would be possible this would make impossible usage of *OAuth 2.0 mechanisms*.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. I am not even sure who is upvoting it.

Comment: Legolas, you keep editing your original question, and then saying the answers are wrong, nice :-D . The answer "no", is still an answer. If you request **restricted resources** then you need to use `Access Tokens`. If they are **public**, then there's no need to grant access and to authorize. The user has explicitly to grant access to private data, otherwise it will not work, there's no way to access it. You still need to use `Client_ID`, as their API has [**Rate Limits**](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/).

Answer (score 4):

Let's not make confusion. Tinder user can opt-in for sharing Instagram photos. Tinder has no worldwide access to Instagram photos. I will answer you from the security perspective, as I have never tried setting up a Tinder account with Instagram connection to test the scenario for you. Actually, from my understanding of [Instagram APIs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) it could be impossible to get user's **private** pictures. But I could be wrong, so let me continue my discussion.

Access token is embedded in Tinder app code, you may find it or not if you decompile the code, according on the level of obfuscation, and almost certainly if you use software such as `mitmproxy`. I won't discuss such a practice here.

So Tinder client is granted a token to access user's pictures.

User opts in on Tinder/Instagram to access his private photos. A single access token is valid for pictures of all users that opted in to Instagram.If you steal Tinder's token you can access any Tinder-Instagram user's private photos. That is not bad. User has chosen to share private photos to the world. But if an Instagram user is not a Tinder user be sure that you won't get anything

Please mind that the token is valid for Tinder application, and **is not** user A's token. This is forbidden by security practices.

By associating your Tinder account with Instagram you *grant* Tinder's already-issued token to access *your photos* on behalf of *you*.

Summarizing:

- Tinder client - Actor
- Instagram - Resource server
- User A's photos - Resource
- User B (on Tinder, not on Instagram) - not an actor in the workflow
- Token issued to Tinder: access to any (public or private??????) photos of users who have **opted in** to share Instagram photos on Tinder

Note: Tinder client **may** or **may not** use an Instagram-issued token. From a general security point-of-view, there are two implementation scenarios:

1. Tinder client contacts Instagram server with a token that is issued to Tinder application and encoded in all clients

   - PRO: bandwidth is charged to user only
   - CON: exposing the token may grant one to access any Tinder-Instagram user photos without passing by Tinder
2. Tinder app requests Tinder server to fetch photos from Instagram. Tinder client only authenticates with Tinder server

   - PRO: more secure design. Tinder-to-Instagram token never exposed. If a user leaves Tinder he can't access Instagram photos of other Tinder users
   - CON: Tinder server will be charged for the bandwidth needed to retrieve and distribute photos. This exposes Tinder to a potential violation of Instagram API ToS if they start caching the photos

Comment: is there a way to view another user's instagram without access token - even private pictures by just using CLIENT_ID?

Comment: No. You must obtain a valid authentication token with an appropriate **scope** to view the user's private picture. From my reading of https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ it seems that there might be no way to obtain user's **private** pictures. My answer applies in general but could be updated

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is way too confusing... so let's handle it in a easy way, according to your question.

Let's start from understanding, what is `access_token`, [in their API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/), in API requests alike:

> api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?**access_token**=%@

Working through API, receiving this `access_token` still requires granting of access, and **Authentication** (see the manual on [Receiving an access_token](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)). As you can read there, all the possible options still require authenticated access.

> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your app should handle the case that either the user **revokes access**, or **Instagram expires the token after some period of time**. If the token is no longer valid, API responses will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError”. In this case you will need to **re-authenticate the user** to obtain a new valid token.
> In other words: do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

This is standard authentication process in programming, with the *access tokens*, *session identifiers*, etc.

The world has been living with [**OAuth 2.0** Authorization Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12) for a long time, you are not the last guy who's concerned about it. If you are sleeping fine knowing about theoretical [Session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), then you shouldn't worry that much about potential security issues related to usage of APIs by access tokens.

It's secure enough. Aha, and another "small thing", I forgotten to mention:  all requests to the Instagram API **must be made over SSL** (http**s**:// not http://), which adds even more confidence.

To answer explicitly your question:

> "is there a way to view another user's instagram without access token - even private pictures by just using CLIENT_ID?"

**No**, there's no possibility. Security token is the thing, which requires granting of access, and authentication. If it would allow this kind of access - this would be counted as security vulnerability. This is the basics of OAuth mechanism. If you need more understanding, you may read here, in a simple language, how [OAuth is an authentication protocol](https://blog.varonis.com/introduction-to-oauth/) works.

Comment: Yes, Tinder works that way right now. Jeez. Without Client - B having to authenticate, all of user- A's pictures are available on the other end.  This means it's possible.

Comment: Question is - there must be an api with just CLIENT_ID, or Tinder passes each other user's access_token to everyone on the app so each client can make the call with that access token

Comment: @Legolas, I think they are using regular API, based on the limits: you will not see all images, but only ~30 recent. I see no problem, to store  access_tokens on the server side on per Tinder User basis. Instagram user still would needs to [sanctify the access](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) for Tinder, so it's not something Tinder may do behind the scenes, without even requesting of permission from Instagram User.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a quick solution to the problem, I would avoid OAuth *at all costs* when dealing with **public** data. I would write a curl script to grab the public Instagram data from the user's profile URL, and parse the HTML server-side (or client-side).

Here's a quick mock-up example in PHP, using `file_get_contents` and `DOMDocument`:

```php
 //HTTP GET someone's profile (the easy way):
 $html = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/profile_xxxxxx/');

 //Use PHP's built-in HTML parser
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);

 $selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

 //Instagram stores image URL's in meta tag "og:image"
 foreach($selector->query('//attribute::*[contains(., \'og:image\')]') as $e) {

   //Store profile photo from DOMNode $e
   $photourl = $e->getAttribute('content');

   //Grab profile photo
   file_get_contents($photourl);
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying to avoid `oAuth 2`, but proposing `file_get_contents`?! It seems you don't understand the purpose at all. No one forbids you to implement Web Server Flow, and keep everything behind the scenes on server side. To me the thing you provided which is **Fetching of data**, is totally different from the task of **Authorization**. Do you understand the difference between these terms at all?

Comment: Plus, separately from that, fetching and storing external volumes of data locally from third party services - is a bad practice, as the traffic and volumes of data are enormous for such social networks. That's why they are using APIs to get references to data laying on the different servers of external services, not on their own server. URLs to different data might also be with expiration, moved to another URL, or even given per specific IP/token basis, in other words, it's not permanent.

Comment: @Farside I think you're overthinking it. All I did was answer "Is there a way to view another user's instagram without requiring access token". And `file_get_contents` doesn't require an access token.

Comment: Yes, Aaron, exactly, you picked up the smallest thing from the whole context, without reading the rest. The question was about accessing public **& private** pictures via API. The whole long story is about `access token` and finding the way of **accessing private** pictures without it. Everyone knows how to load and fetch the public data, so your answer is not exactly to the point. Can you please elaborate also this thing: *"avoid OAuth at all costs"*? it would be interesting to hear why.

Comment: @Farside Personal opinion. OAuth is the most poorly documented concept I've ever ran into as a web developer, specifically Twitter OAuth. I understand the security aspect: using tokens to protect users' passwords from 3rd parties, but the developer aspect (sessions, cookies, post data, callbacks) is a nightmare. If it weren't for the (one) working example, I would have hired an assistant by now.

Answer (score -2):

Let's consider that Instagram User Profiles pages like ISS page are available online without any authentication access:

https://www.instagram.com/iss/

Due to how Instagram works, only public images will be showed here (plus posts, followers, following).

So what you have to do is to get the page data. To do this you can use several solutions like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that is as little as writing

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.instagram.com/iss/', function() {
   var contents=page.contents; // here is the page contents
   phantom.exit();
});
```

So, assumed you can execute this process on server-side you could provide those public profile images as a JSON object in a api response. Of course it's a little bit more complicated than this (i.e. you have to wait page resources to be loaded within `PhantomJS`, but at the end the web scraper can temporary save the page and turn it into a json structure, with `<img/>` source images, etc. ready to be showed in a app.